# Silverlight SOS (Son of Strike) documentation

Tags: silverlight, windbg, sos

Is there any Microsoft or even non-official documentation for SOS for Silverlight.  Other than a few web posts I have seen zero documentation for it on MSDN.  Even official documentation for the CLR version of SOS seems hard to find, this ancient [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2003/june/bugslayer-sos-it-s-not-just-an-abba-song-anymore) mentions a sos.htm file that is included in the windows SDK but it doesn't appear to be there anymore.  Any pointers to debugging Silverlight with SOS?  I have found the following blog posts but am looking for more information:

http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/08/finding-memory-leaks-in-silverlight-with-windbg/ 
http://www.ningzhang.org/2008/12/19/silverlight-debugging-with-windbg-and-sos/ 
http://debuggingblog.com/wp/2009/07/07/windbg-extension-sos-in-clr-40net-framework-40-ctp-net-runtime-dll-renamed-and-sos-commands-just-got-richer/ 
http://www.netfxharmonics.com/label/debugging 
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150731005804/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/tess/archive/2008/08/21/debugging-silverlight-applications-with-windbg-and-sos-dll.aspx) 
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150629123240/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/delay/archive/2009/03/11/where-s-your-leak-at-using-windbg-sos-and-gcroot-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak.aspx) 
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151008001026/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/delay/archive/2009/03/09/controls-are-like-diapers-you-don-t-want-a-leaky-one-implementing-the-weakevent-pattern-on-silverlight-with-the-weakeventlistener-class.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using SOS to debug Silverlight should be the same as debugging the regular framework.  !help is a good place to start to see all the commands SOS exposes.

Is there something else you're looking for?